# using a Python Win32Com .py in Unix - QC OTA library

Tags: python, unix, python-2.7, hp-quality-center, comobject

Please forgive me if my question confuses you.

I have to use HP Quality Center's `QC OTA Library (DLL)` in my Python Script. 
I was able to do this on my Windows System after Registering that DLL using `Com Makepy Utility` . The utility gave me a .py for that .dll inside the gen_py folder.

Here is my question,

Will i be able to use that same registered .py file on a Unix system as well? or 
Do i have any other alternatives to let my Python Script use that Quality Center Library file in Unix as Python compatible class?

Answer (score 0):

OTA is a win 32 COM library. In theory it's not intended to run on Linux.
You can try to use WINE on linux but you will need to run your python application inside WINE as well.